# Is it reasonable to use sqlite for a low traffic web application?

Tags: sqlite, datamapper

I've always thought of and used SQLite as a tool for client side storage.

But I am developing a low traffic web application, with simple storage and querying requirements.

Is it reasonable (and/or at all common) to use SQLite on the backend of a web application, where I would generally use MySQL?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts on this subject.

UPDATE:

Thanks for responses.

1) Yes, it would remain low traffic as it is being designed for a small, predefined group of users.

2) I would be using an ORM and no SQLite specific features, so switching to MySQL, as you say, should not be a big issue if it became necessary.

3) @stealthyninja: Would you say 100 insert/updates per day would qualify as very infrequently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mp11: Read through [Appropriate Uses for SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html), it should give you a good idea of whether or not SQLite is suited to your project...but yes, if you're going to insert/update *very* infrequently, then SQLite can be much quicker to just query.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say 100 insert/updates per day would qualify as very infrequently?